# How to make text to hide with overflow hidden in table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell that I want to hide overflow text over `100px` in width. It's here, but it still shows overflow text: http://jsfiddle.net/tkatcqwe/

```css
.text {
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td class='text'>a really long text about random things, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.text {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td class='text'>a really long text about random things, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td></tr></table>
```

try adding a max-width of 100px to your .text
added snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text into a `<div>` or any block level element, or a `<span>` + `display:block` if you want to keep the table untouched.

```css
.text {
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td><div class='text'>a really long text about random things, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div></td></tr></table>
```

Or set `width:100px` on the table instead + [`table-layout:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout).

```css
table {
    width: 100px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.text {
    background: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td class='text'>a really long text about random things, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td></tr></table>
```